# Nativescript stopped working

Tags: nativescript

My nativescript just stopped working. I'm on Windows 10. I installed everything and it all was working OK until I restarted my laptop. Now I get an error -unexpected token - when executing any 'tns' command. See attached screendump. I've tried reinstalling but this does not work. Any ideas?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1YPD.png)

Comment: Post the code and error here directly.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was fixed here and so is now closed. https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2011